# Need to call 4 functions on 1 click ignoring the params

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, I have this code which its been called once the app loads

```
$scope.postDashboardsData = function (dataType, dateFrom, dateTo) {

    console.log('DATA', dataType, dateFrom, dateTo);

    $scope[dataType + '_done'] = false;

    return Api.post('rotations/' + vm.data[0]._id + '/dashboard', angular.extend({
        type : dataType, //"overall", "clicks-conversion", "traffic-sources", "devices"
        date_range : {
          from : dateFrom,
          to : dateTo
        }
      }, vm.data));
  }

  $scope.postDashboardsData('overall', $scope.datepickerConf1.overall, $scope.datepickerConf2.overall)
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.overallData = data;
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

  $scope.postDashboardsData('clicks-conversion', $scope.datepickerConf1.clicksConv, $scope.datepickerConf2.clicksConv)
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.clicksConversionData = data;
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    });

  $scope.postDashboardsData('traffic-sources', $scope.datepickerConf1.traffic, $scope.datepickerConf2.traffic)
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.trafficSourcesData = data;
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

  $scope.postDashboardsData('devices', $scope.datepickerConf1.devices, $scope.datepickerConf2.devices)
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.devicesData = data;
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

so as you see, there are 4 calls to the api once the app loads. If some of that information change, I need to do a process button in the view in order to make the 4 calls again with the new data, like this

```
<button ng-click="postDashboardsData(dataType, dateFrom, dateTo)">
```

so, what can I do to make the 4 calls to the api in only 1 button ?

Comment: you can use `&` in ng-click or make a function which calls all other functions.

Comment: @Sachin can you help me with a piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need a wrapper function that loops through all the types

```
$scope.loadAll = function(from, to){
    ['overall', 'clicks-conversion', 'traffic-sources','devices'].forEach(function(dataType){
        $scope.postDashboardsData(dataType, from, to);
    });
}
```

Then for button:

```
<button ng-click="loadAll( dateFrom, dateTo)">
```